# Large screens layout not as expected

Tags: android, android-layout

I developed and application and uploaded all the images in the respective drawable folders (different pixels for different desnities).

Now I am confused when it comes to layout. If  I used the layout editor with 4.1 inc (thats considered Med screen I guess?) everything looks great.
Now when I use the editor with 10.1 inch which is the tablet, then I see icons very small and the text is small. I have not run the emulator yet.
So I am wondering:

1- why would the text be small although I didn't specify text size? Shouldnt scalle appropriately? or should I give it a specific size for bigger layouts?

2- Why the icons are small given that I provided the different drawables? I thought it would scale up accordingly.

Please don't give me the supporting multiple screens link in android as an answer, as I already went through it and still no luck with above. I need your personal advice as I think I am missing something here

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not specify the text size in your layout file Android will take the default value, which is most likely in DIP (density independent pixel) therefore it will be the same physical size on any devices. That should explain why the text looks so small on your 10 inch tablet.

What I would do in this case is have 3 layouts for each activities and specify the text size for larger devices (given you already like the look on phones) and put them in this folder scheme :

```
res/layout/layout.xml           // phones
res/layout-sw600dp/layout.xml   // 7” tablets
res/layout-sw720dp/layout.xml   // 10” tablets
```

Information above was taken in [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html). I have this applied in my current personal project and so far it works like a charm.

Secondly, as far as icons go, I'm no drawable expert but if you provided the same file in each folder (like I think you did from what I understand in your question), it will not make it scale. You'll have to create 4 difference icons, one for each possible pixel density.

Information about icon sizes can be found on [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html).

Hope this is of some help to you.

Comment: Perfect. I like your direct answer that is specific to my problem. I wish there is a website though that lists all devices along with their densities and screen size

Comment: Sorely incompatible with Android less than 3.2.

Comment: Devices running anything less than 3.2 will always be phones, therefore they will grab the default layout won't they ?

Answer (score 1):

Android support for different screens is a little tricky. That's because you can have *large*, *small*, *medium* and *xlarge* screens, plus *high*, *medium* and *low* density ones. There are a dozen possibilities (xlarge low density, small high density) and not **a single resolution is defined**. So you must know [the principles](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) which the API is designed upon and must define your layout thinking about **the role** the widget has inside your UI. You also must bear in mind that your layout won't be pixel perfect on 100% of devices, so your aim should be being *usable* on all possible devices.

In your specific case it seems that either you don't manage to specify the *correct* resources, or the system doesn't pick up the right ones for you, but I must remark that it doesn't make sense on Android to talk about *big*, *small* and *scale*: you should design your layout with a (good) webdeveloper mindset, who daily deals with tons of different displays, resolutions, physical sizes and even devices.

I also suggest not using the graphical builder if you are new to Android, because you **really** need to know how Android lays out components, otherwise you will come back to SO very often :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is more of how to think rather than how to solve. good to keep them in mind

Answer (score 0):

My experience with the Android device zoo drew me to the sad conclusion that the built-in screen size/layout facility is useless. Cases in point, straight from support:

- a 10 inch tablet with Android 2.2. Screen size xlarge is not supported by Android 2.2
- Kindle Fire, which is 7 inch and claims it's xlarge.

I ended up putting all three layouts (med/large/xlarge) into `layout`, loading one based on run-time density and resolution, and providing an option for user to force a specific layout.

Just sayin'.